# Grails XML converters - change root node name

Tags: grails, groovy

I have following code in my groovy class and I want to change the name for root node. My domain object name is EMP and I want to change it to  when I convert my domain in XML.

```
def init = {
    XML.registerObjectMarshaller Emp
     { emp, xml ->
        xml.build {
          emp_name(emp.name)
          emp_dept(emp.dept)
        }
      }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the root name you will need to use the `NameAwareMarshaller` which is slightly more complicated than the implementation you are currently using.

While slightly dated, this [blog entry](http://jwicz.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/grails-custom-xml-marshaller/) explains all the steps in detail. In particular you want to pay attention to the `startNode` property of the converter.

```
public void marshalObject(Object object, XML converter) {
  Foo foo = object as Foo

  converter.startNode 'name'
  converter.chars foo.name
  converter.end()

  Map map = [firstKey: 'firstValue', secondKey: 'secondValue']
  converter.startNode 'locallyDefinedMap'
  converter.convertAnother map
  converter.end()
}
```